# LAN not connecting

Tags: 22.04, internet, lan

I am using my college LAN cable and it requires login user name and password. My problem is that Log in page does not appear many times. I am clicking on the network symbol again and again (I mean switching On/Off LAN). Then after 40-50 times doing this fortunately login page appear. I am using Ubuntu 23.10.

I will be great thankful for any help.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.